# Typescript visual Studio Project Property

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2013

What "Specify root directory for TypeScript files"in VS2013 Project Properties means?

Answer (score 0):

This corresponds to the `--sourceRoot` command-line parameter, which is used when you need the emitted source maps to specify the location of the TypeScript files in a path than would be the default. For example, you might have a script at `http://example.com/script.js`, but your source files might be in `http://example.com/src/script.ts`.

If you don't already know that this is the thing you need, it can safely be ignored.